# how to replace string that contains a variable, the next string that contains variables

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file "a.sh":

```
...
AB="${VAR}/example/ep
...
```

First, I make sure that the text is in the file. I use this:

```
old='AB="${VAR}/example/ep'
if grep -qxF ${old} a.sh; then
   echo "YES"
else
   echo "NO"
fi
```

When I am sure that the text is in the file, I want to replace it with:

```
new='AB="${VAR}/example/ep;${VAR}'
```

I am trying to use:

```
sed -i "s/$old/$new/g" a.sh
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different delimiter for `s`:

```
old='AB="${VAR}/example/ep'
new='AB="${VAR}/example/ep;${VAR}'
echo 'AB="${VAR}/example/ep' | sed "s|$old|$new|"
```

Output:

```
AB="${VAR}/example/ep;${VAR}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `sed` is [happy with any delimiter](https://coderwall.com/p/khdkuw) you want to give it. So by using the `|` as opposed to `/`, `sed` does not become confused with the `/` characters in your string.

```
#!/bin/sh

old='AB="${VAR}/example/ep'
new='AB="${VAR}/example/ep;${VAR}'

if grep -qxF ${old} a.sh; then
    echo "YES"
else
    echo "NO"
fi

sed -i "s|$old|$new|g" a.sh
```

This can be confirmed by using your original code (not the code above) and modifying your original `old` and `new` variables with escape characters like below.

```
old='AB="${VAR}\/example\/ep'
new='AB="${VAR}\/example\/ep;${VAR}'
```

With this version, your `grep` call won't find it because it doesn't like the escape characters, but it will get replaced by `sed`.

Ultimately, using the `|` delimiter is going to be your easiest fix as it doesn't break your `grep` call and it makes your variables work with `sed`

Comment: I'm not sure how this gives a different idea from my answer.

Comment: You didn't offer any explanation for your answer. The point of Stack Overflow, as I understand it, is to share knowledge and experience, not just to fix code.

Comment: I believe my answer can be easily understood well enough. And I don't think SO has that kind of guideline or restriction. Only the community built it. And the community is not SO itself. But anyway it's ok. No worries :) Peace. I'll give you my +1.

Comment: Well, thank you for the +1, and you're right, Stack Overflow doesn't have that restriction, I guess I just like to explain things :-) I appreciate your kindness and patience :-) I wish everyone had your attitude :-)